# Multi-machine Vagrant with Ubuntu - Sinatra & PostgreSQL

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, vagrant, provisioning

I'm stuck again. I need to provision a multi-machine Environment - one VM for a Sinatra app and a second for its PostgreSQL DB.

So far, I've managed to get the Sinatra app up and running in the ubuntu/xenial64 box but the provisioning "breaks" when it hits the configuration for the DB

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define "app" do |app|
    # Use ubuntu/xenial64 as the virtual machine
    app.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
    # Use a private network to connect the VM to the local machine via an IP with an alias
    app.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.100"
    app.hostsupdater.aliases = ["development.local"]
    # sync the 'app' directory in the local directory to '/app' on the VM
    app.vm.synced_folder "app", "/app"
    # Use the provisioning script in envirnonment to provision the VM for a Sinatra environment
    app.vm.provision "shell", path: "environment/app/provision.sh"
    app.vm.provision "shell", inline: set_env({ DATABASE_URL: "postgresql://myapp:dbpass@localhost:15432/myapp" })
  end

  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    db.vm.host_name = "postgresql"
    db.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.2.15"
    # db.vm.forward_port 8000, 8000
    db.hostsupdater.aliases = ["database.local"]
    # db.vm.share_folder "home", "/home/vagrant", ".", :create => true
    db.vm.provision "shell", path: "environment/db/provision.sh", privileged: false
  end

end
```

As you've probably guessed, I'm running an external provisioning script for the PG setup. The odd thing is I'm using the script recommended from Postgres' own site [here](https://github.com/jackdb/pg-app-dev-vm).

In a separate location, I've git cloned that repo and followed the instructions and it works absolutely fine, creating a properly provisioned VM with PG installed.

However, I want to run a single `vagrant up` command and provisioning both the app and db correctly and have them speak to each other.

I'm (quite clearly) new to provisioning and DevOps as a whole, so would really appreciate some help.

I've uploaded my hilariously broken code [here](https://github.com/jjwmcgregor/sinatra_postgresql_vagrant) for you kind souls to look over if you feel so inclined.

Vagrant documentation on Multi-machines is quite thin and Google isn't being much help

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this tagged Ruby?

Comment: Looking at the PG script I think you need the root privileges to run it, try removing the ` privileged: false` attribute from the provisioner(the default is true). And please share the error you receive in any case.

Comment: @anothermh - Sinatra is a Ruby MVC framework

Comment: I changed the tags so the appropriate people see this and you get better help.

Comment: JJ, you should improve the question by explaining *exactly* what you mean by "it breaks". We're not mind readers (at least, I hope we're not!)

Comment: @lee-pai-long that worked, thank you!

Comment: @iain fair point - the issue was a) it wouldn't provision the DB VM with Postgresql, and b) I can't connect the App VM to the Postgres DB VM. a) is now working, so now working on b)

Comment: @JJMcGregor I know what Sinatra is, I've written many Sinatra apps. I asked why this question is tagged Ruby since your question has nothing to do with Ruby. Tags should only be applied when they are relevant to the question. "[Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)"; the tags bash, shell, Ruby, and Sinatra are all irrelevant.